# The fully-relativistic classic solution of 2 electrons starting from rest?

Tags: electromagnetism, special-relativity, thought-experiment

Has anyone seen the following problem in an article or a textbook?

Consider 2 electrons initially at rest at $\pm x_0$ in the lab frame.  Describe the fully-relativistic, i.e. solving Maxwell's equations, trajectories of these electrons as a function of time assuming that the only interaction between them is electromagnetic, i.e. no gravity, no strong force, and no weak force.

Obviously, I want the inclusion of such effects as the electromagnetic wave emission due to acceleration, retardation effects, and the simple relativistic limit of the speed of light (the last of which is easy to get if the other effects are ignored).  Any published or on-line discussion of this problem, even if it lacks a solution, is what I am truly interested in.

Comment: So reading more about this, I came across the Darwin Lagrangian (it's even in Jackson).  While not exact, I think it might be what I need...

Comment: Nope.  Darwin Lagrangians do not capture retardation.

Comment: Is it not more apporpriate to apply Coulomb's law (rather than Maxwell) to solve this problem?

Comment: Coulomb's law can lead to a force, yes, but I am not sure if this force is valid.  Specifically,  the distance between the electrons cannot be instantaneously assumed (as is the general case with Coulomb's law) as the electric flux propagates at the speed of light.  If the purely Coulomb force is assumed, it overestimates the momentum of the particles.  This may appear as if the energy is not conserved, but the accelerating electrons generate electromagnetic radiation that preserves energy conservation.  A mathematical treatise on this problem is what I am looking for.

Comment: I think I found the paper I was looking for... https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0003491674904503

Comment: So there appears to be substantial thought on this issue, and it is fairly complicated.  There is a paper by Driver (1973) called "Can the future influence the past?" that deals with this case explicitly (at least existence and uniqueness) and something more recent paper (2018) by Bauer et al. that looks at a general proof of existence and uniqueness.   However, nothing that actually provides a closed analytic form as far as I can tell.

Comment: I guess its possible an analytical solution has not been found; it's rather like the three body problems in that it is a two body problem with something else going on too.